# The Process class relies on proc_open, which is not available on your PHP installation

Tags: php, laravel, apache

проблема в том что при установке Laravel 6 на хостинг (используется php 7.3.0) выдает такой error log:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

ответ сапорта не совсем мне понятен:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не первый раз устанавливаю Laravel на хостинг но с такой ошибкой встречаюсь в первой.
В интернете было найдено решение которое мне не подошло:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=flare-config
```

И внести изменения в файле config/flare.php

```
'reporting' => [
    'anonymize_ips' => true,
    'collect_git_information' => false,
    'report_queries' => true,
    'maximum_number_of_collected_queries' => 200,
    'report_query_bindings' => true,
    'report_view_data' => true,
],
```

За ранее спасибо !

Comment: Ваш код Laravel в процессе установки пытается вызвать запрещённые функции. Видимо, хостинг запретил создавать процессы через консоль, так что вам нужно вручную проделать необходимые движения на локалке, и залить после всего этого на хостинг, не прибегая к использованию vendor:publish (и, вероятно, всем другим консольным командам) на сервере.

Comment: Вы не подскажете что именно нужно сделать ? Ну или хотя бы в какую сторону гуглить?

Comment: Я уже написал выше, и вам ответили с техподдержки - убедитесть что все необходимое сделано на локалке, запускайте все команды на локалке, и уже после этого заливайте на хостинг, без запуска каких-либо команд там.

Answer (score 0):

Для меня рабочим решением стало в папке bootstrap/cache/config.php изменение параметра 'collect_git_information' => true, на false